# Transitive gem not resolving correctly

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.1.6.1) was resolved to 5.1.6.1, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.1.6.1)

    web-console (~> 3.7.0) was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
```

Shouldn't the transitive `activemodel`  of `web-console` resolve to 5.1.6.1? Maybe I am confused on how these gems are being resolved.

Regardless these should be compatible.

The entire message:

```
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.1.6.1) was resolved to 5.1.6.1, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.1.6.1)

    web-console (~> 3.7.0) was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
      railties (< 5.1.x, >= 4.0.0)

    jquery-rails was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 5.1.6.1) was resolved to 5.1.6.1, which depends on
      railties (= 5.1.6.1)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

    web-console (~> 3.7.0) was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.0)
```

Comment: Is that the **full** error message? I'm willing to bet there are some more lines below, which properly explain the error.

Comment: Like, further down it probably says something like : `gem "the-real-problem" (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.2.3, which depends on activemodel (< 5.0)`

Comment: I updated the description to include the entire message, but I do not think the rest of the message has any affect on activemodel

Comment: Did you specify a version of `activemodel` in the `Gemfile`? Regardless, can you share the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`? You're right that this is quite an odd error, if indeed that's the full message.

Comment: You can try blowing away your lockfile and reinstalling dependencies (if you're confident that you won't break anything by doing so)

Comment: @DavidS. Not confident :(

Comment: @TomLord I have tried specifying the version in the Gemfile as well. Nothing.

Comment: @Chris back up your lockfile and try anyway! It may work.

Comment: OO well that worked out nicely. @DavidS. ;)